# Page rank for multiplex heterogenous network (r or python implementation)

Tags: graph, networkx, igraph, pagerank

Is there an implementation of page rank for multiplex heterogeneous networks? Similar to https://rdrr.io/bioc/pageRank/man/multiplex_page_rank.html but for heterogenous network, where different layers have nodes of different nature and layers are connected through some links.

Comment: Can you give a mathematically precise definition of what you want to compute?